# Cannot install EntityFramework 6.1.3 on my Web API .Net Core Project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, nuget, .net-core

I want to ask for help on how to install EntityFramework on my web api project (.net core).

I tried installing it but it keeps showing the error **"Package restore failed. Rolling back packages.."**

Is EntityFramework compatible on web api?

Thanks in advance for your response. Have a good day!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Search for **EntityFrameworkCore**
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a .Net Core Mvc project which is the combine Web Api and Mvc for Core the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, which you most likely already have installed, already include this.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) says

> To add EF Core support to a project, install the database provider
>   that you want to target. This tutorial uses SQL Server, and the
>   provider package is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. This
>   package is included in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage, so
>   you don't have to install it.